# MS Access If Record Exists for Person

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have the following VBA code that I wanted to use before realising it was not correct;

```
Len(DLookup("Service_User_ID", "tblPurchaseOrders", "Service_User_ID=" & .Person_ID) > 0) And IsNull(DLookup("Purchase_Order_Number", "tblPurchaseOrders", "Purchase_Order_Number='" & .Purchase_Order & "'"))
```

What I want the code to do is to check if the `Purchase_Order_Number` exists for records with that `Service_User_ID`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check for *Null*:

```
Found = Not IsNull(DLookup("Service_User_ID", "tblPurchaseOrders", "Service_User_ID = " & .Person_ID & " And Purchase_Order_Number = '" & .Purchase_Order & "'"))
```

Comment: Is this checking that they exists as one record?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your table fields correctly since I presume the Purchase_Order_Number is unique? If that's the case, why do you need the Service_User_ID?

Anyways, try this.

Wrap it in a function to be able to call it from multiple places.

```
Function OrderExists(ByVal purchaseOrder As String, ByVal personId As Long)
    OrderExists = DCount("Purchase_Order_Number", "tblPurchaseOrders", "Purchase_Order_Number='" & purchaseOrder & "' AND Service_User_ID=" & personId) > 0
End Function
```

To call it:

```
Sub T()

    Dim bool As Boolean
    bool = OrderExists("ABCD", 112)

    Debug.Print bool
End Sub
```

Comment: Although PON is unique, what if someone passes a record with both existent PON and SUI but the PON is not for that SUI. That's what I want to catch.

Comment: I understood what you mean. I believe you should break it down into two parts. 1) Check the order exists 2) if the order exists, validate the SUI.

Comment: Is that what you solution is doing?

Comment: No, not really. It returns True only if both PON and SUI supplied exist in table.